# Why is this Insertion Sort of linked list taking longer than usual?

Tags: c, sorting, insertion-sort

This is supposed to be an efficient code, but it's taking much longer than what a normal insertion sort would take. I can't identify what's the problem with this insertion sort. Is there an implementation problem?

```
// function to sort a singly linked list using insertion sort
    void insertionSort(element_t **head_ref)
{
    // Initialize sorted linked list
    element_t *sorted = NULL;

    // Traverse the given linked list and insert every
    // node to sorted
    element_t *current = *head_ref;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        // Store next for next iteration
        element_t *next = current->next;

        // insert current in sorted linked list
        sortedInsert(&sorted, current);

        // Update current
        current = next;
    }

    // Update head_ref to point to sorted linked list
    *head_ref = sorted;
}


/* function to insert a new_node in a list. Note that this
  function expects a pointer to head_ref as this can modify the
  head of the input linked list (similar to push())*/
void sortedInsert(element_t** head_ref, element_t* new_node)
{
    element_t* current;
    /* Special case for the head end */
    if (*head_ref == NULL || (*head_ref)->val >= new_node->val)
    {
        new_node->next = *head_ref;
        *head_ref = new_node;
    }
    else
    {
        /* Locate the node before the point of insertion */
        current = *head_ref;
        while (current->next!=NULL &&
               current->next->val < new_node->val)
        {
            current = current->next;
        }
        new_node->next = current->next;




current->next = new_node;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the code is working correctly, it should probably be posted to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: Do you have any example of normal insertion sort you can compare yours version with?

Comment: How long is the list, and how long did it take to sort?

Comment: I would expect your code to finish in 3 to 5 minutes. How long did it take?

Comment: A function that I do not have access to (recursive sort) sorted the list in  0.108833 seconds... My function should be similar to this, but it seems that it's way too far if you're right

Comment: its not really a good sorting algorithm for linked lists regardless. You can certainly improve your `sortedInsert` function ([example here](http://pastebin.com/1CtaQMxu)), but the complexity is still going to be dreadful. A puny little MacBook Air laptop circa 2011 takes about 35sec on -O3 opt, as I would expect. Merge sort is a much better algorithm for linked lists (and perhaps what your mystery "recursive sort" is doing).

Comment: Insertion sort is an O(N^2) algorithm. The other sort is most likely an O(NlogN) algorithm. Roughly speaking, the insertion will take 5 billion operations to sort 100000 elements, whereas an O(NlogN) sort will take only 1.7 million operations, about 3000 times faster. So if the O(NlogN) sort takes 0.1 seconds, the insertion sort takes about 5 minutes.

Comment: A bottom up merge sort for linked lists using a small (25 to 32) array of pointers to nodes should be the fastest way to sort a linked list. [wiki example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists). [example c program](http://code.geeksforgeeks.org/Mcr1Bf) .

Comment: Even a simple l2r scanning bottom-up merge-sort will be significantly better than insertion sort on anything larger than a trivial node list. IOn the OP's case, a 100k node sort of random values on that puny MBA mentioned earlier delivers < 0.07ms with such an algorithm. Insertion sort is simply not a good match for that data structure and size. It works best on small, cache-friendly, random-accessible data sets,  attributes that a linked list of 100K nodes has exactly none of.